# Why can't I used data attr in my site but I can on other sites?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm hoping you can give me some pointers... For some reason when I try and use the data attr on my site I'm unable to get access to it via jquery.

[I've made a jsfiddle showing I can use this ok](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKE3/) but using the same code I end up with a blank.

What do you think could be causing this? Has this happened to you and were you able to debug it?

My site is html5 and passes validation.

Any pointers you could give me to look into would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** 
I realised that I was running on a version of jquery that didn't yet supporting using the data model yet :|

Comment: What version of jQuery ? You can also get those attributes with `.attr()` (but then you have to include the prefix `data-`)

Comment: In jQuery docs says: **"...and also reserves any data name starting with an underscore ('_') for internal use."**. I know in your code the data attribute is not starting with an underscore but try changing `data-booking_id` for `data-booking-id`.

Comment: @ChrisAbrams Its a backend app unfortunately.

Comment: @JoseAdrian Its a long shot. I'll give it a try tho!

Comment: @DidierGhys thats right. currently I am getting it via $('#id').attr('data-booking_id') - but it would be nice to use the data tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to conflict in jQuery versions or with other js frameworks using $ method, check once by just typing $ in your browser console which will return something like

```
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
```

if the problem is with conflicts then use [jquery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). To check jquery versions use

```
$().jquery; (or)
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

Comment: If I put a $ in the console, all I get returned is: 'function()'. I've just realised I'm running 1.4.2! The version before data became accessible. hmm... oops.